# Db2 - how to assign value to a variable with EXECUTE statement in db2

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, db2

I'm tring to execute query in a db2 procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST (IN indbnm VARCHAR(30), IN intblnm VARCHAR(30))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE statmnt2 VARCHAR(1000); 
DECLARE VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU CHAR(1);  
DECLARE stmt1 STATEMENT; 

SET statmnt2 = 'SELECT COD_TIPO_ARQU FROM '||indbnm||'.'||intblnm||' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY';
PREPARE stmt1 FROM statmnt2;
SET VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU = EXECUTE (stmt1);
END@
```

This gives following error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0206N  "STMT1" is not valid in the context where it is used.  LINE 
NUMBER=33.  SQLSTATE=42703
```

What's the right way to set `VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU` with `COD_TIPO_ARQU` value dynamically?

ThankYou.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the way you are setting the result from the execution:

```
EXECUTE stmt1 into VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU ;
```

This is the complete code that is executed succefuly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST (IN indbnm VARCHAR(30), IN intblnm VARCHAR(30))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE statmnt2 VARCHAR(1000); 
DECLARE VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU CHAR(1);  
DECLARE stmt1 STATEMENT; 

SET statmnt2 = 'SELECT COD_TIPO_ARQU FROM '||indbnm||'.'||intblnm||' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY';
PREPARE stmt1 FROM statmnt2;
EXECUTE stmt1 into VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU ;
END@
```

Comment: Hi @AngocA , 
I traied: 'EXECUTE stmt1 into VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU ;' 
But its givig me a error: 
'SQL0518N The statement named in the EXECUTE statement is not in a prepared state or is a SELECT or VALUES statement. SQLSTATE=07003'

Answer (score 2):

Hi is it correct solutuion:

```
SET statmnt = 'SELECT COD_TIPO_ARQU FROM '||indbnm||'.'||intblnm||' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY';
PREPARE stmt1 FROM statmnt;

BEGIN 
    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR stmt1;
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 into sttmresult;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

TY.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked, but I found that none of the given answers worked.

@AngocA's solution was close but, as @Mani_Swetha pointed out, the `EXECUTE` statement fails due to the `SELECT` bit.

After searching and combining solutions around the web, this is what finally worked for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST (IN indbnm VARCHAR(30), IN intblnm VARCHAR(30))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE statmnt2 VARCHAR(1000); 
DECLARE VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU CHAR(1);  
DECLARE stmt1 STATEMENT; 

SET statmnt2 = 'set ? = (SELECT COD_TIPO_ARQU FROM '||indbnm||'.'||intblnm||' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)';
PREPARE stmt1 FROM statmnt2;
EXECUTE stmt1 into VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU ;
END@
```

Note that now the executed command is a `set` statement with a `SELECT` inside, rather than a pure `SELECT` statement. This is what makes the trick.

Comment: How to call this stored procedure and retrieve the result set in `VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU`? Don't you have to set the `OUT` parameter in the declaration?

Comment: @Îsh Yes, if you want to get the value outside of the procedure, just use an OUT variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Marcos `EXECUTE... INTO ...` worked.

Additionally, creating the stored proc with `OUT` parameter will let you access the value set by `EXECUTE... INTO ...` outside the stored proc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ISH.SAMPLEPROC (OUT o_result VARCHAR(5))
specific proc_user_data_retrieval
dynamic result sets 1
reads sql data
language sql
BEGIN
DECLARE stmt varchar(5000) default null;
DECLARE VAR_X VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE stmt_final STATEMENT;
SET stmt = 'SET (?) = ('||'SELECT JOB_ROLE FROM ISH.USER_DATA LIMIT 1'||')';
PREPARE stmt_final FROM stmt;
EXECUTE stmt_final INTO VAR_X;
SET o_result = VAR_X;
END
```

Then call the stored proc using `CALL ISH.SAMPLEPROC(?);`